# A question about the Peano form of the remainder in a function's Maclaurin formula?

Tags: analysis, taylor-expansion

Let the function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be $n$ times differentiable at $x=0$, and we have $$f(x)=P_n(x)+o(x^n)$$ where $P_n(x)$ is the $n$-th order Taylor polynomial and $o(x^n)$ is the Peano form of the remainder. Then we surely have $$f(x^2)=P_n(x^2)+o(x^{2n})$$. But in the textbook I'm using, it goes like$$f(x^2)=P_n(x^2)+o(x^{2n+1})$$ How to prove it? 

Here's my effort: Let $g(x)=o(x^n)$, then we have $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{g(x)}{x^n} =0$, but it doesn't imply that  $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{g(x^2)}{x^{2n+1}} =0$. I guess the Peano form of the remainder may not be an ordinary "Little-O of $x$", but I can't find out the extra information about it. Could anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact you stated is clearly wrong (so, as stated, the claim of your textbook is wrong). Indeed, define:

$$\begin{array}[t]{ccccc}
f&:&\mathbb{R}&\longrightarrow&\mathbb{R}\\
&&x&\longmapsto&\lvert x\rvert^{5/4}
\end{array}$$
Then $f$ is differentiable at $0$ since:
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=0.$$
Now,
$$f(x)\underset{x\to0}=o(x).$$
Here $P_1(x)=0$.
Yet,
$$\frac{f\bigl(x^2\bigr)-P_1\bigl(x^2\bigr)}{x^3}=\frac{\lvert x\rvert^{5/2}}{x^3}\underset{x\to0}{\not\to}0\qquad\text{since $5/2<3.$}$$

We hence showed that there exists a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ that is $1$ time differentiable at $0$ (case $n=1$) and such that
$$f\bigl(x^2\bigr)\underset{x\to0}{\not=}P_1\bigl(x^2\bigr)+o\bigl(x^3\bigr).$$

This counterexample can easily be adapted to any $n$ (and not only $n=1$).